# Как посчитать время программы? python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import time
n = 33

start_recur = time.time()
def fib(n):
    if (n == 1) or (n == 2):
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
end_recur = time.time()

x = 0
x1 = 1
x2 = 1

start_loop = time.time()
for i in range(2, n):
    x = x1 + x2
    x1, x2 = x2, x
end_loop = time.time()


print('loop', x, end_loop-start_loop)
print('recursion', fib(n), end_recur-start_recur)
```

вывод:

```
loop 3524578 0.0
recursion 3524578 0.0
```

Я хотел бы спросить, почему в обоих случаях выводит 0, хотя программа работала довольно таки долго. И как это исправить?

Comment: с функцией я, вроде разобрался, что вызов функции нужно заключить между start_recur и stop_recur, а не саму функцию, но с циклом до сих пор думаю

Comment: у меня пара комментариев. 1)Вы вызываете свою функцию `fib` внутри `print`. . Получается, что вы просто меряете время ее создания, а не время ее работы. 2) Во всех подобных проблемах просто выводите значения всех переменных в консоль. Чаще всего поймете, что не так.

Answer (score 3):

Сам решил, простите, что отвлёк. если кому нужно оставлю тут решение.
С рекурсиями всё просто нужно заключать не рекурсию, а вызов функции

ПРАВИЛЬНО:

```
def fib(n):
    somecode
start_recur = time.time()
fib(n)
end_recur = time.time()
```

НЕПРАВИЛЬНО:

```
start_recur = time.time()
def fib(n):
    somecode
end_recur = time.time()
fib(n)
```

с циклом всё норм, он просто очень быстрый, смог засечь время только при очень больших цифрах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если что-то не так сказал поправьте, пожалуйста,

Comment: хотя как отметил комментатор выше, во втором случае мы измеряем время создание, а не время работы функции

Answer (score 2):

Цикл реально будет работать очень быстро.

У вас там 31 итерация и в каждой только сложение и обмен значений. Это очень быстрые операции, там просто нечему долго работать.

На моей машине цикл выполняется за 0,000017 секунд.

Возможно, в вашем случае почему-то происходит округление до целых секунд.

Возможно, это связано с тем, что

> Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second. While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls.
>   (официальная документация)

(Краткий перевод: не все системы предоставляют время с точностью, большей чем 1 секунда).

Попробуйте на вашей системе многократно позапускать `print(time.time())` и посмотрите - будет ли это вам выдавать дробные значения, или только значения, округлённые до целого.